# Why is eventName of IntermediateThrowEvent always null?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I've created the following BPMN with the camunda modeler.

[image]

All works fine.

1. starting the process (with processVariable *someVar* == null)
2. complete **usertask A**
3. eventsubcription **wait until condition is met** becomes active
4. setting processVariable *someVar* to non-null value
5. **usertask B** becomes active
6. complete **usertask B**
7. process ends

My question is about the event in the middle: **wait until condition is met**.
This event checks a processVariable. If the processVariable is != null, the process continues to **usertask B**.

In the BPMN xml file it is define in this part

```
<bpmn:intermediateCatchEvent id="IntermediateThrowEvent_1f8yyme" name="wait until condition is met">
      <bpmn:incoming>SequenceFlow_01qic24</bpmn:incoming>
      <bpmn:outgoing>SequenceFlow_0g3ju49</bpmn:outgoing>
      <bpmn:conditionalEventDefinition>
        <bpmn:condition xsi:type="bpmn:tFormalExpression">${someVar != null}</bpmn:condition>
      </bpmn:conditionalEventDefinition>
</bpmn:intermediateCatchEvent>
```

I clearly define a name on the bpmn:intermediateCatchEvent element. The name is also visible in the camundo modeler.

However, when I query the EventSubscriptions in step 3, I get indeed the EventSubscription, but the eventName is null.

I'm using this code for EventSubscriptions retrieval

```
runtimeService.createEventSubscriptionQuery()
  .processInstanceId(processInstance.getProcessInstanceId())
  .list();
```

Also, checking the databasetable act_ru_event_subscr also shows an empty column event_name_

I need this name since I want to make the 'current' activities of processes available to the user. 
For activities such as usertasks, this is no problem, but for intermediateEvents I'm not able to retrieve the name.

Am I missing something?